# Anchor link to elements on the same page not working?

Tags: html

The href links in my list are not moving the page to the corresponding elements on the same page. I can see the change in the url but nothing on screen.

```
<div id="allSections">

    <!--ALL SIDE SECTIONS-------------------------->
     <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#hero">Welcome</a></li>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#branches">Venues</a></li>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#reservation">Reservation</a></li>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#map">Map</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div>
        <section name="#hero" id="#hero">
            <div>
                <div id="imgContainer">
                    <img src="images/2017-02-26_004802.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section name="#branches" id="#branches"></section>

        <section name="#reservation" id="#reservation"></section>

        <section name="#contactus" id="#contactus"></section>

        <section name="#map" id="#map"></section>
    </div>

    <!--ALL SIDE SECTIONS----------------------------->

</div>
```

Comment: Remove the # from you section ids.

Answer (score 1):

Change your section to:

```
   <section id="branches"></section>

   <section id="reservation"></section>

   <section id="contactus"></section>

   <section id="map"></section>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was stupid. I don't know how I didn't see that. :)